# Working on different database from stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Please do me a favor, I want to maintain all the stored procedures in one database, let's say `SP_Dbase`.

I plan this scheme, user application determine `dbase_xyz` and will go to `SP_stored_procedure` in `SP_Dbase` and then retrieve or edit data of `dbase_xyz`.

Since command `Use dbasename` does not work in a stored procedure, I have big difficulty.

I don't intend to write down all the procedure as an execute command as follows :

```
Set @cmd = 'select .... from ' + @DB + '.dbo.tablename'
EXEC(@cmd)
```

Anyone could help me ?

Note: All databases have same structure and exist in one SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a **horribly bad** idea .... what are you trying to achieve by doing this??

Comment: I agree - what is the purpose of this? It's really not too hard to set up a system to replicate your stored procedures out to a bunch of databases if you are worried about code duplication.